# What I doing wrong with Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

this is my test code:

```
public function testTransceiverEntityCreate()
{
    $transceiver_driver = Mockery::mock('Recoder\Drivers\TransceiverDriverInterface');
    $transceiver_driver->shouldReceive('load');

    $transceiver_utils = Mockery::mock('TransceiverUtils');

    new Transceiver('1F2D03', $transceiver_utils, $transceiver_driver);
}
```

When I running tests it returns follows error:

`1) TransceiverTest::testTransceiverEntityCreate
Argument 2 passed to Recoder\Entities\Transceiver::__construct() must be an instance of Recoder\TransceiverUtils, instance of Mockery_2__TransceiverUtils given, called in /var/www/solidoptics-recorder/private/application/libraries/Recoder/tests/Entities/TransceiverTest.php on line 35 and defined`

Why Mockery_2__TransceiverUtils? I would be happy for any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the class is not found so Mockery mocks it totally instead of extending it. The class must be already loaded, or loadable via autoloading.